# How do you generate JSON file when input text has different property names?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

When you have a text file like:

```
apple
mango
orange

cat
dog

toyota
mazda
opel
```

how do you generate JSON file using Python3 which should look like:

```
{ 
  "fruit_1": "apple",
  "fruit_2": "mango",
  "fruit_3": "orange",
  "animal_1": "cat",
  "animal_2": "dog",
  "brand_1": "toyota",
  "brand_2": "mazda",
  "brand_3": "opel",
}
```

Comment: There's no *completely general* way to do this, unless the text file is already pre-grouped by category. How it the  file generated? Is each group always separated by blank lines, and do the groups always appear in the same order?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, each group is pre-grouped and separated by blank like ("\n"). In fact, I have several clusters each consisting these three groups and separated by 'cluster_1', 'cluster_2', and so on. So, I have to write code for that too. But, no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Is there always exactly *one* blank line between the groups? If so, you can simply do something like `[c.split() for c in open(filename).read().strip().split('\n\n')]` to get a list of lists.